# request parameters not working properly when called from inside iframe

Tags: jsp, struts

I have a search page called search.jsp. I have a corresponding struts search action for this page. Everything works perfect when u click on "search" link.

My search page url is something like

```
      http://www.localhost:8080/Search.ff?blah=1&popo=2
```

Now i am calling the same search page from a different page of my website inside an iframe.

I use the same url now as a iframe  src url

```
     http://www.localhost:8080/Search.ff?blah=1&popo=2&showheader=yes
```

I try to get the parameter inside search.jsp page as

```
     <% String showheader =  (String)request.getParamter("showheader"); %>
```

when i debugged showheader was null.

I want that when the search page is called within iframe i should not display the search page header.

I don't understand what the real problem and how can i rectify the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<% String showheader =  (String)request.getParameter("showheader"); %>
```

(The difference are the quotes)

Comment: sorry i forget to put it here.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo either in the iframe src URL or in the JSP code?
Did you verify, that showheader is not null, when you insert the src URL in the browser address bar?

Comment: I verified and I was also expecting the variable there. But to my surprise it's not coming there at all the jsp page. I have a question like when the call the jsp page is the struts method get called first and then the action class renders the jsp page or the jsp page get called directly.

Comment: Then you probably have a misunderstanding how the parameers are handled in your application. What type of object is this "request"?
Where does it come from?

Comment: i padd this parameter in the frame src url and try to receive this parameter in the jsp page. this is just a boolean variable.